# CodeBlocks on Ubuntu does not come up

Tags: ubuntu

I installed CodeBlocks on Ubuntu Hardy heron running on amd64 machine. The installation went fine but when i invoke it from the Menu, i see a busy cursor for sometime but the application does not come up.

How do i get it working?

Answer (score 3):

The CodeBlocks user manual can be found [here](http://www.codeblocks.org/user-manual), the FAQ [here](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=FAQ), the wiki [here](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/), and the forum [here](http://forums.codeblocks.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Run the command from a terminal and see if it produces any diagnostics. You can find the command that is run by editing the menu (right click on applications) and you will find the terminal under Applications -> Accessories.

If no diagnostic output is produced, check the documentation to see if there are command line switches to like --debug or --verbose that will cause it to emit more diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are it isn't finding libcodeblocks.so.0.0.1 this is a bug in the makefile install you need to manually copy it from src/sdk/.libs/ to /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib

```
sudo cp src/sdk/.libs/libcodeblocks.so.0.0.1 /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libcodeblocks.so.0.0.1 /usr/lib/libcodeblocks.so.0
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libcodeblocks.so.0.0.1 /usr/lib/libcodeblocks.so
sudo ldconfig
```

And you should have code blocks up and running.